# Long waiting time for computing a summation

Tags: recursion, summation, sequence

It takes a long time to compute the summation below, and I'd like to know if there are alternative ways
to compute things faster. When replacing $15$ by $\infty$, then I should get $3^{1/3}$. I need Mathematica  solution
not mathematical solutions (since here I can handle things on my own).

```
Clear[b, k]
b[0] := 1;
b[k_] := b[k - 1] + 1/(b[k - 1]^2 + b[k - 1] + 1)
N[1/(15)^(1/3) Sum[1/(b[k]^2 + b[k] + 1), {k, 0, 15}]]
```

Comment: I'd like to see what happens when I set $1000$ instead of $15$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
Clear[b, k]
b[0] := 1;
b[k_] := ( b[k] = N[b[k - 1] + 1/(b[k - 1]^2 + b[k - 1] + 1), 100] )
1/(1000)^(1/3) Sum[1/(b[k]^2 + b[k] + 1), {k, 0, 1000}]

(*1.28966188938645818444514220128278717806515296115261423714827563492762\
  4979228386408865750383532338923*)
```

very close to `3^(1/3) = 1.4422...`

The convergence is slow. So you should do extrapolation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1). It seems that $N$ in front caused some trouble.

Comment: yeah, the limit is precisely $3^{1/3}$.

Comment: I actually put `N` in the definition of b[k], since its exact values are huge rational numbers.

Comment: Note that here `k` is local variable, so it is not necessary to `Clear` it at the beginning of the code.

Comment: I got the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
b[0] := 1;
b[k_] := b[k] = N[b[k - 1] + 1/(b[k - 1]^2 + b[k - 1] + 1)]
f[x_] := f[x] = f[x - 1] + (1/(b[x]^2 + b[x] + 1))
f[0] := 0

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Table[1/x^(1/3) f[x], {x, 1, a}], MaxPlotPoints -> 100, 
  Epilog -> {Green, Line[{{1, 3^(1/3)}, {a, 3^(1/3)}}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 4}], {a, 10, 100000, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative,

```
Nest[# + 1/(1 + # + #^2) &, 1., n + 1] - 1
```

that will compute the sum over `0 <= k <= n`.  For 100-digit precision use

```
Nest[# + 1/(1 + # + #^2) &, 1.`100, n + 1] - 1
```

Examples

```
With[{n = 1000}, 
  1/n^(1/3) (Nest[# + 1/(1 + # + #^2) &, 1.`, n + 1] - 
     1)] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000359, 1.28966} *)

With[{n = 1000}, 
  1/n^(1/3) (Nest[# + 1/(1 + # + #^2) &, 1.`100, n + 1] - 1)] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.005293, 
    1.28966188938645818444514220128278717806515296115261423714827563492762\
      4979228386408865750383532338923} *)

With[{n = 1000000}, 
  1/n^(1/3) (Nest[# + 1/(1 + # + #^2) &, 1.`100, n + 1] - 1)] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.204264,
    1.42720128317421809656439478563254431280673078216998116597726119064353\
      220814168138689903801038204268} *)
```

It avoids the recursion and memory limits that the OP's `b` runs into.  (With `n = 1000000`, my kernel crashed using `b` and `Sum`.)  And you can use `NestList` to get all the sums up to `n`.